# Pass this parameter in javascript function using href

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have code `<a href="javascript:someFunction(this);" tabindex="0">Some text</a>`

Is it possible to pass  element into `someFunction(link) {...}` and use it later.

In debug mode I see the object but all properties are *undefined*.

When I was using onClick attribute like `<a onClick="javascript:someFunction(this);` it worked fine.

I am aware that this is probably not the best solution and I have seen the other questions, but it is really not my issue right now. I just need to do it this way for many reasons.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried that?  Go ahead and try it and see if it works.  It looks correct to me.

Comment: don't do inline javascript! no excuses, just don't do it.

Comment: `onclick` has a `this` parameter because it triggers an event. `href` does not.

Comment: @Blender:can I pass this with href?

Comment: @Mathletics: How can I achieve that action is happened on press Enter if <a> element has focus, and still this to be passed in javascript method?

Comment: `onclick` is triggered as an event, but clicking on the link doesn't *trigger* anything. It just lets the browser reload the page. `this`, in that context, is undefined because there is no event.

Comment: @Mathletics: Why no inline javascript? People code as they want, nothing forbids it.

Comment: @Nabab — Best practises forbid it. Write [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), make use of [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [separate your concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: Why downvote?? Can't I ask the question?

Comment: @Nabab: It doesn't scale well. What if you have 20 links like that? I'm lazy and really don't want to copy & paste that inline code into every link I create.

Comment: The expression best practices and the verb to forbid don't go together ;)

Comment: @Blender: I got it there is no event with hrer so this is undefined, but it does not reload the page if we put href="javascript:someFunction(); Then I probably need event that handles click on the <a> and enter press on the <a>, in both cases I need this passed in function that is executed on the event. Is there something like that? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you replacing onclick with href, if onclick worked fine for you?

Comment: @Christophe: Because I need to support keyboard navigation and href call the function when enter is pressed.

Comment: So you're applying a hack to try to work around a hack that didn't work for some people, and the hack is causing more problems. Just do it properly instead of trying to bandaid the hack further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using jQuery (disregard this answer if you don't), you can attach an event to your link:

```
$('#id_of_your_link').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  someFunction(this);
});
```

This code works for both keyboard navigation and mouse clicking: http://jsbin.com/ufapor. You can see the source code here: http://jsbin.com/ufapor/edit#javascript,html

Comment: it seems that his is my answer, I was not aware that I can do it this way http://jsbin.com/ufapor/4/edit#javascript,html  Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Ok... I see what has happened here.  The problem is that when you trigger an onclick event, there is an element involved.  Thus you can pass `this` and reference it in the function.  But when you use `href`, you are setting the current location to whatever is in that `href`.  It's the same as if you typed it in the address bar and hit enter.  Therefore, if you pass that function `this`, it's actually referring to the DOMWindow object.  The only way around it that I can see, is to instead pass the node's `id` to the function as plain text.  Then grab it with `getElementById`.

I would highly recommend reconsidering how you are doing this though.

Comment: Thanks I this I have found the solution.